# How to manipulate a string with the grep command?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a filename with the format `yyyymmdd.txt`. How can I output only `yyyymmdd` without the `.txt` extension?

Example

```
20220414.txt (before output)
20220414 (after the output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` doesn't manipulate anything, it shows what you have in a file. So, you can't modify that file using `grep`, but you can modify what it shows, using the `-o` switch, as you can see here:

```
Prompt> echo "20220414.txt" | grep -o "[0-9]*"
20220414
```

The `[0-9]*` means "a list of integers, going from character `'0'` to character `'9'`.

Answer (score 2):

`basename` has an option to remove a suffix:

```
basename -s .txt 20220414.txt
```

gives:

```
20220414
```

Or, if your filename is stored in a variable, bash can help:

```
a=20220414.txt
echo ${a%.*}
```

gives:

```
20220414
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user `awk` with flag `-F` to specify the separator `.` and then print the first part with `$1`

```
echo "20220414.txt" | awk -F  "." ' {print $1}'
```

output

```
20220414
```